# Using Angular JS with Requires JS with : Menu hover event not binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I have a application in angular js.I am using the Requires js to load my js files. Now the problem is I have a menu item with the drop-down list which (menu html) need to be present before i load my respective js for menu so it can bind the hover event to menu. I have loaded the menu template via ng-include .So now what happens when i load my js files at that time my html is not rendered due to angular load the html inside the ng-include after the app has bootstrapped. So the menu js file are not able to bind the event as html not present at js load time .

Any onr knows how to deal with this in angular js files.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer , it was very simple , tell the required to load the js file after the angular has bootstrapped the application.

here is how my boos trapper file look like now.

```
define(
    ['angular','controllers','directives','filters','services','common-controllers','require'],
    function (angular,controllers,directives,filters,services,commonControllers) {
        var app = angular.module('app',['controllers','directives','filters','services','common-controllers']);
        app.init = function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            require(['bootstrap-tpls','gsap','jquery-ui','bootstrap','joinable','resizeable','custom'],function(){
            });
        }

        return app;
    }
);
```

This line has done the trick

```
require(['bootstrap-tpls','gsap','jquery-ui','bootstrap','joinable','resizeable','custom'],function(){
            });
```